# Do the Demons always give the same bonus?

Tags: doodle-devil

I have tried them a couple of times and it seems to always give the same bonus.

[image: a Picture of all the Demons]

But I find that Baal in particular is very disappointing (1 gold).

Do the Demons always give the same bonus when you activate them?

or is there some randomness and I have been unlucky with Baal?

or is there a trick to getting better bonus from some of them?